# Check the render method of `MaterialTopTabNavigator`

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-top-tabs

I want to create a Top Tab navigator and put two screens Badges.js and Studying.js into Tab when I run it on my device I get an error it says **"Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string ..."** and **"Check the render method of `MaterialTopTabNavigator"**.

**TabScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image, Text} from 'react-native';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import Badges from './Badge';
import Studying from './Studying';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const TabsScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Badges" component={Badges} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Studying" component={Studying} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
export default TabsScreen;
```

**Badges.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image, Text} from 'react-native';

const Badges = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Badges</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Badges;
```

**Studying.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image, Text} from 'react-native';

const Studying = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Studying</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Studying;
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Ali!
Can you please write the full error message? Your code for Tab Bar looks good. From the error "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string ...", it looks like an "object" is being supplied to a `<Text />` component instead of "string".

Comment: Not sure this was a mistake or not the `import Badges from './Badge'` file name is wrong.

Comment: Hi Ajay, Thank you for your comment. when I change createMaterialTopTabNavigator with createBottomTabNavigator my program work, I want to show my tabs at the top of the screen.                                                                                                           
**Error:** Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports'

Comment: and  error **Check the render method of `MaterialTopTabNavigator`**

Comment: I tried to reproduce the above bug and I can confirm it is due to the wrong file name `import Badges from './Badge'` `./Badge` should be `./Badges`

Comment: I change`./Badge` to `./Badges` but don't work

Comment: Can you throw a https://snack.expo.io/ demo, and reproduce the issue in that snack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure all the following packages have same version

```
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.1",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.1",
```

Comment: thanks for your response, unfortunately it's not working for me.

Comment: I have them all but facing same issue

Comment: You don't have to have them in the exact same version.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. This is mi solution (npm or yarn don't problem)

a) Unistall more update version 6.0.0

```
yarn remove react-navigation/material-top-tabs
```

b) Install this version in my case 5.3.15

```
yarn add @react-navigation/material-top-tabs@5.3.15
```

[image]

c) stop and start your proyect and work
[image]
[image]

d) Continue with the oficial documentation
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#example

Comment: thanks but not working for me.