# createTopTabNavigator().Navigator is undefined in react native top tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I tried to use material-top-tabs from react navigation. I have followed the installation process mentioned in their documentation. But when I try to import createMaterialTopTabNavigator

*Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
imports.
Check the render method of `MaterialTopTabNavigator`.*

This is the code I have written. All other imports work fine.

````
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
// import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import {
  MostViewedSongsScreen,
  RecentlyPlayedSongsScreen,
} from "./history-screens";
import {
  backgroundColor,
  black60,
  black80,
  matteBlack,
} from "../others/constants";
import TabBarContents from "../components/HistoryScreen/TabBarContents";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
// const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
export function HistoryScreen() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      // tabBarOptions={{
      //   // activeTintColor: "white",
      //   // inactiveTintColor: "white",
      //   activeBackgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      //   // inactiveBackgroundColor: "white",
      //   showLabel: false,
      //   style: {
      //     position: "absolute",
      //     bottom: 0,

      //     elevation: 5,
      //     backgroundColor: black80,
      //     height: 60,
      //     textAlign: "center",
      //   },
      // }}
      initialRouteName="most-viewed-songs"
      // tabBar={(props) => <TabBarContents {...props} />}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="most-viewed-songs"
        component={MostViewedSongsScreen}
        // options={{
        //   tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        //     return (
        //       <View
        //         style={{
        //           alignItems: "center",
        //           justifyContent: "center",
        //           // top: 10,
        //         }}
        //       >
        //         <Icon
        //           name="account-clock-outline"
        //           size={26}
        //           color="white"
        //           style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}
        //         />
        //         <Text
        //           style={{
        //             color: "white",
        //             ...styles.baseTextStyle,
        //           }}
        //         >
        //           Most Viewed
        //         </Text>
        //       </View>
        //     );
        //   },
        // }}
      ></Tab.Screen>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="recently-played-songs"
        component={RecentlyPlayedSongsScreen}
        // options={{
        //   tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        //     return (
        //       <View
        //         style={{
        //           alignItems: "center",
        //           justifyContent: "center",
        //         }}
        //       >
        //         <Icon
        //           name="history"
        //           size={26}
        //           color="white"
        //           style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}
        //         />
        //         <Text
        //           style={{
        //             color: focused ? backgroundColor : "white",
        //             ...styles.baseTextStyle,
        //           }}
        //         >
        //           Recently Played
        //         </Text>
        //       </View>
        //     );
        //   },
        // }}
      ></Tab.Screen>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  baseTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 14,
    textTransform: "capitalize",
    letterSpacing: 1.05,
    color: "white",
  },
});```


my package.json dependencies are 
```  "dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.16.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.17",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-av": "~9.2.3",
    "expo-clipboard": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "lottie-react-native": "4.0.2",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-animated-loader": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-image-colors": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-palette": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "rn-placeholder": "^3.0.3"
  }```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check the render method of \`MaterialTopTabNavigator\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68611993/check-the-render-method-of-materialtoptabnavigator)

Comment: I have updated the react-navigation package to v6 and it worked.